# Prepros: Watching all files but compile only main

Tags: css, sass, prepros

I have a problem with Prepros configuration.

I want to watch for changes in all `*.scss` files in my project, but I want to compile only the `style.css` file.

[image]

Content of style.scss:

```
@import "_bootstrap";
@import "_bootstrap-compass.scss";
@import "_bootstrap-mincer.scss";
@import "_bootstrap-sprockets.scss";
```

I managed to configure my main file `scss/style.scss` to compile to file `style.css`. Compilation works ok. But I don't want to do that manually, everytime I make a change in some file.

Is there a way to watch for changes in all `*.scss` files? And when a change occurs, is there a way to tell Prepros to trigger `style.scss` compilation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the underscore characters and .scss file extensions from your @imports, save the file & reload prepros.

```
@import "_bootstrap-compass.scss";
```

*will become*

```
@import "bootstrap-compass";
```

I find that if I have my projects set up like this it somehow works more reliably, but that being said it's supposed to work either way. The file watcher is meant to compile your *main* stylesheet whenever any included files are updated.

If that doesn't work I'd recommend removing the project and adding it again *(be sure to delete the config file in the project folder)*, then restarting Prepros.